# Mantener una variable disponible en varios script

Tags: php

Cordial saludo.
Agradezco me indique como puedo hacer para que una variable que tengo disponible en un script, pueda ser utilizada en otros script que funcionaran en el mismo sitio web.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado, javascript tiene una opción llamada **localStorage**, con esta puedes guardar un valor el cual puedes hacer uso de él cada vez que sea necesario, para hacer el uso de esto, te dejo un ejemplo a continuación:

```
     localStorage.setItem("nombrevariable", variableAsignada);
```

- **nombrevariable** : esta será la variable por la cual podrás obtener en javascript.
- **variableAsignada**: esta será la variable que quieres guardar.

luego para poder hacer uso de esta variable solo debes realizar la siguiente llamada en cualquier script o archivo script dentro de tu proyecto.

```
localStorage.getItem("nombrevariable");
```

esto lo puedes asignar a una variable para mayor comodidad.

```
var variable =  localStorage.getItem("nombrevariable");
```

espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos.